# How to get only specific attributes with from Laravel Collection?

Tags: laravel, collections, eloquent

How can I get all specific IDs from the collection in Laravel 8 ??

I'm trying to get `food_item_id` from collection by foreach loop. But I only get first item ID. I want not only the first item but also  all item Ids.

I want to get all `food_item_id` form here.

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1083 ▼
    #items: array:2 [▼
    0 => App\Models\Cart {#1082 ▼
      #guarded: []
      #connection: "mysql"
      #table: "carts"
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #keyType: "int"
      +incrementing: true
      #with: []
      #withCount: []
      #perPage: 15
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      #attributes: array:8 [▼
        "id" => 265
        "food_item_id" => 6
        "user_id" => 3
        "quantity" => 3
        "price" => 124
        "total_price" => 372
        "created_at" => "2021-01-28 08:22:16"
        "updated_at" => "2021-01-28 08:51:51"
      ]
      #original: array:8 [▶]
      #changes: []
      #casts: []
      #classCastCache: []
      #dates: []
      #dateFormat: null
      #appends: []
      #dispatchesEvents: []
      #observables: []
      #relations: []
      #touches: []
      +timestamps: true
      #hidden: []
      #visible: []
      #fillable: []
    }
    1 => App\Models\Cart {#1291 ▼
      #guarded: []
      #connection: "mysql"
      #table: "carts"
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #keyType: "int"
      +incrementing: true
      #with: []
      #withCount: []
      #perPage: 15
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      #attributes: array:8 [▼
        "id" => 267
        "food_item_id" => 4
        "user_id" => 3
        "quantity" => 1
        "price" => 179
        "total_price" => 179
        "created_at" => "2021-01-28 08:51:54"
        "updated_at" => "2021-01-28 08:51:54"
      ]
      #original: array:8 [▶]
      #changes: []
      #casts: []
      #classCastCache: []
      #dates: []
      #dateFormat: null
      #appends: []
      #dispatchesEvents: []
      #observables: []
      #relations: []
      #touches: []
      +timestamps: true
      #hidden: []
      #visible: []
      #fillable: []
    }
  ]
}
```

I did this

```
$food_item_ids = $food_item_id->pluck('food_item_id')->all();
```

I get an array of ID, Now I want to find this

```
 $food_item = FoodItemPrice::where('food_item_id', $food_item_ids)->get();
```

I want to find FoodItemPrice ID which match with food_item_ids .

Comment: Post your code that you have tried?

Comment: Please post the expected result.

Answer (score 1):

You're working with a [`collection`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections) which Laravel provides some very handy [helper methods](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#available-methods) for. The one you're specifically after would be [`pluck`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-pluck).

```
$food_item_ids = $collection->pluck('food_item_id')->all();
```

**Update**

Assuming `$food_item_ids` in the above has a collection of `ids` and you want to use them to find your `$food_items` using those `ids`, then you could do:

```
$food_items = FoodItemPrice::whereIn('food_item_id', $food_item_ids)->all());
```

Comment: It shows this error Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::all()

Comment: Is `FoodItemPrice` an eloquent model?

Answer (score 0):

To get all an array of all values of a specific field/attribute of a collection, you can use the `pluck()`

So you could do something like:

```php
$items = Cart::all();
$foodItemIds = $items->pluck('food_item_id');
```

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-pluck